# How to enable cURL in CentOS 5?

Tags: curl

i already installed cURL with:
**yum install curl**

I restarted the httpd service but cURL is still not loaded. What else needs to be done?

Thanks!

Comment: You may find what you're after here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332133/how-to-add-curl-support-to-php-5-in-centos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean as a PHP module? I believe it's php5-curl, but just try searching yum.

The package 'curl' is just the command-line curl client.

Comment: yum info php5-curl returns nothing =( -- same for php-curl or php4-curl

Comment: wait... yum install php-curl did work, but it didnt get automatically configured in the php.ini config file. i'll get on that now ;) thanks

Comment: It might go into /etc/php.d/curl.ini, RPMs usually do.

Comment: nope... no curl.ini found. I also cannot find the curl.so or libcurl.so to configure the extension =( any way to install php curl automatically?

Answer (score 2):

curl.so needs to go into the extensions directory within your `apache/httpd` directory. Check your Apache logs and if you have curl module enabled, it'll tell you why it fails to load.

My issue was that the curl.so had to be moved from `/usr/lib64/php/blah blah` to the `directory-apache's-installed/php/extentions/no-debug-zts-20131226/` and I bounced apache and the page fired right up!

Good luck